# SQL Select MIN Priority

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that has four union subqueries of the different scenarios of pricing for each customer. In each union I have assigned a value as Priority to rank scenario from lowest to highest. However, when I run the query if a customer has a product price in scenario 1 it also shows it for scenario 2, 3, and 4. I've tried to select `MIN(a.Priority)`but it still shows for each union. I have been able to make this work by using `WHERE not exits (SELECT 1 FROM ("Previous Union")` but is there a more efficient way to do this? Below is my query.

Clarifying my question. I'm trying to return the minimum priority for each customer and item code.

```
select a.CustomerNo,a.CustomerName,a.ItemCode, a.ItemCodeDesc,a.ProductLine, a.PriceCode,a.CustomerPriceLevel,
    a.Price, a.Priority as [Priority]  from
    (Select a.CustomerNo,b.CustomerName,c.ItemCode, c.ItemCodeDesc,c.ProductLine, c.PriceCode, 'Item Specific' as [CustomerPriceLevel], (c.StandardUnitCost + a.DiscountMarkup1) as [Price], 1 as [Priority]
From dbo.IM_PriceCode as a
inner join dbo.AR_Customer as b on a.CustomerNo=b.CustomerNo
inner join dbo.CI_Item as c on a.ItemCode=c.ItemCode
where c.PrimaryVendorNo='0000002' and c.InactiveItem='N' and (b.UDF_NATIONALACCNT='N' or b.UDF_NATIONALACCNT='') and a.PricingMethod <>'R'

UNION ALL

    Select a.CustomerNo,c.CustomerName,b.ItemCode, b.ItemCodeDesc,a.ProductLine, a.PriceCode, a.CustomerPriceLevel, (b.StandardUnitCost + d.DiscountMarkup1) as [Price], 2 as [Priority]
From dbo.IM040_CustomerSpecialPricing as a
inner join dbo.CI_Item as b on a.PriceCode = b.PriceCode and b.ProductLine = a.ProductLine
inner join dbo.IM_PriceCode as d on b.ItemCode = d.ItemCode and d.CustomerPriceLevel = a.CustomerPriceLevel
inner join dbo.AR_Customer as c on a.CustomerNo = c.CustomerNo
where b.PrimaryVendorNo = '0000002' and b.InactiveItem = 'N' and a.ProductLine <> '' and (a.PriceCode = 'BLK' or a.PriceCode = 'HDBK' or a.PriceCode = 'PDBK')


UNION ALL

SELECT        a.CustomerNo,a.CustomerName,c.ItemCode,c.ItemCodeDesc,b.ProductLine,b.PriceCode,b.CustomerPriceLevel,
            case
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'J' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitPrice*1.15
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'D' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitPrice*1.2
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'V' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitPrice*1.25
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'C' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitPrice*1.3
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RJ' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.15
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RD' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.2
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RV' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.25
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RC' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.3
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'J' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.20
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'D' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.25
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'V' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.35
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'C' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.45
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RV' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.1
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RC' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.15
                else 0
                end as [Price], 3 as [Priority]     
        
FROM            dbo.AR_Customer AS a
                inner join dbo.IM040_CustomerSpecialPricing as b on a.CustomerNo = b. CustomerNo
                inner join dbo.CI_Item as c on c.PriceCode = b.PriceCode and c.ProductLine=b.ProductLine            
where c.PrimaryVendorNo = '0000002' and b.ProductLine<>'' and  c.InactiveItem = 'N' and (b.PriceCode= 'PKG' or b.PriceCode='COOL')

UNION ALL

Select a.CustomerNo,c.CustomerName,b.ItemCode, b.ItemCodeDesc, a.ProductLine, a.PriceCode, a.CustomerPriceLevel,
        case
            when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'J' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitPrice*1.15
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'D' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitPrice*1.2
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'V' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitPrice*1.25
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'C' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitPrice*1.3
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RJ' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.15
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RD' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.2
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RV' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.25
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RC' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.3
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'J' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.20
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'D' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.25
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'V' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.35
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'C' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.45
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RV' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.1
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RC' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.15
                else 0
                end as [Price], 4 as [Priority]
From dbo.IM040_CustomerSpecialPricing as a
inner join dbo.CI_Item as b on a.PriceCode = b.PriceCode
inner join dbo.AR_Customer as c on a.CustomerNo = c.CustomerNo
where b.PrimaryVendorNo = '0000002' and b.InactiveItem = 'N' and a.ProductLine='' and (a.PriceCode = 'PKG' or a.PriceCode = 'COOL')

) as a
```

Comment: are you absolutly sure about mysql, bracket are not a escape character in mysql

Comment: Sorry, I type sql in tag and clicked it. I have removed it from tags. This is a SQL server running SQLManagement Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE with your query as basis and use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the minimum `priority` by `customer` and `product`

```
WITH CTE AS (select a.CustomerNo,a.CustomerName,a.ItemCode, a.ItemCodeDesc,a.ProductLine, a.PriceCode,a.CustomerPriceLevel,
    a.Price, a.Priority as [Priority]  from
    (Select a.CustomerNo,b.CustomerName,c.ItemCode, c.ItemCodeDesc,c.ProductLine, c.PriceCode, 'Item Specific' as [CustomerPriceLevel], (c.StandardUnitCost + a.DiscountMarkup1) as [Price], 1 as [Priority]
From dbo.IM_PriceCode as a
inner join dbo.AR_Customer as b on a.CustomerNo=b.CustomerNo
inner join dbo.CI_Item as c on a.ItemCode=c.ItemCode
where c.PrimaryVendorNo='0000002' and c.InactiveItem='N' and (b.UDF_NATIONALACCNT='N' or b.UDF_NATIONALACCNT='') and a.PricingMethod <>'R'

UNION ALL

    Select a.CustomerNo,c.CustomerName,b.ItemCode, b.ItemCodeDesc,a.ProductLine, a.PriceCode, a.CustomerPriceLevel, (b.StandardUnitCost + d.DiscountMarkup1) as [Price], 2 as [Priority]
From dbo.IM040_CustomerSpecialPricing as a
inner join dbo.CI_Item as b on a.PriceCode = b.PriceCode and b.ProductLine = a.ProductLine
inner join dbo.IM_PriceCode as d on b.ItemCode = d.ItemCode and d.CustomerPriceLevel = a.CustomerPriceLevel
inner join dbo.AR_Customer as c on a.CustomerNo = c.CustomerNo
where b.PrimaryVendorNo = '0000002' and b.InactiveItem = 'N' and a.ProductLine <> '' and (a.PriceCode = 'BLK' or a.PriceCode = 'HDBK' or a.PriceCode = 'PDBK')


UNION ALL

SELECT        a.CustomerNo,a.CustomerName,c.ItemCode,c.ItemCodeDesc,b.ProductLine,b.PriceCode,b.CustomerPriceLevel,
            case
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'J' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitPrice*1.15
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'D' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitPrice*1.2
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'V' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitPrice*1.25
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'C' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitPrice*1.3
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RJ' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.15
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RD' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.2
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RV' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.25
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RC' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.3
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'J' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.20
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'D' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.25
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'V' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.35
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'C' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.45
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RV' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.1
                when b.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RC' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then c.StandardUnitCost*1.15
                else 0
                end as [Price], 3 as [Priority]     
        
FROM            dbo.AR_Customer AS a
                inner join dbo.IM040_CustomerSpecialPricing as b on a.CustomerNo = b. CustomerNo
                inner join dbo.CI_Item as c on c.PriceCode = b.PriceCode and c.ProductLine=b.ProductLine            
where c.PrimaryVendorNo = '0000002' and b.ProductLine<>'' and  c.InactiveItem = 'N' and (b.PriceCode= 'PKG' or b.PriceCode='COOL')

UNION ALL

Select a.CustomerNo,c.CustomerName,b.ItemCode, b.ItemCodeDesc, a.ProductLine, a.PriceCode, a.CustomerPriceLevel,
        case
            when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'J' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitPrice*1.15
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'D' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitPrice*1.2
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'V' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitPrice*1.25
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'C' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitPrice*1.3
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RJ' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.15
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RD' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.2
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RV' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.25
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RC' and b.PriceCode = 'PKG' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.3
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'J' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.20
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'D' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.25
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'V' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.35
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'C' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.45
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RV' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.1
                when a.CustomerPriceLevel = 'RC' and b.PriceCode = 'COOL' Then b.StandardUnitCost*1.15
                else 0
                end as [Price], 4 as [Priority]
From dbo.IM040_CustomerSpecialPricing as a
inner join dbo.CI_Item as b on a.PriceCode = b.PriceCode
inner join dbo.AR_Customer as c on a.CustomerNo = c.CustomerNo
where b.PrimaryVendorNo = '0000002' and b.InactiveItem = 'N' and a.ProductLine='' and (a.PriceCode = 'PKG' or a.PriceCode = 'COOL')

) as a
), CTE2 as(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ustomer,product ORDER BY [Priority] ASC) rn  
FROM CTE 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: That only returned first record.

Comment: yes you wanted the minimum as far as i nderstood also without data play with it i can only guess the wanted result and tag your database sysrtem you are using

Comment: The minimum priority for each customer and product. I clarified my question above.

Comment: i chnage the the part bafter the first cte to get your data